# Java Card OwnerPin - APDU Command

Tags: javacard, apdu

I'm starting to learn java card and I'm reading a sample code of a wallet and there an `OwnerPin` in it.

Here's the part of the code, related to the pin and its verification:

```
OwnerPIN pin;

private myApplet(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {

    // It is good programming practice to allocate
    // all the memory that an applet needs during
    // its lifetime inside the constructor
    pin = new OwnerPIN(PIN_TRY_LIMIT, MAX_PIN_SIZE);

    byte iLen = bArray[bOffset]; // aid length
    bOffset = (short) (bOffset + iLen + 1);
    byte cLen = bArray[bOffset]; // info length
    bOffset = (short) (bOffset + cLen + 1);
    byte aLen = bArray[bOffset]; // applet data length

    // The installation parameters contain the PIN
    // initialization value
    pin.update(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), aLen);
    register();

}
```

I'm having a little trouble understanding this code. I know that this is the part when the pin is set according to the installation script:

```
0x80 0xB8 0x00 0x00 0xd 0xb 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7F;
```

I can't understand what is the value of pin will be after installing the applet.

Comment: If `0x0B` is the length of the AID then `0x00` before `0x7F` is the PIN length, indicating an empty PIN.

Comment: Is this by any chance used with jcardsim for testing? The CLA-INS combination `0x80 0xB8` is used by jcardsim for creating an applet.

Answer (score 1):

The shown code is not enough to actually say anything about the given APDU.

This code sample though:

```
byte iLen = bArray[bOffset]; // aid length
bOffset = (short) (bOffset + iLen + 1);
byte cLen = bArray[bOffset]; // info length
bOffset = (short) (bOffset + cLen + 1);
byte aLen = bArray[bOffset]; // applet data length
```

is the default code for the Applet's `installation` method, therefore could be triggered by a Global Platform INSTALL command. However, the given APDU is not a valid Global Platform at all.

From your code we cannot see the entrypoint of the APDU in the `process` method, but probably it works like this: the given data is a LV-encoded list (Length/Value), therefore you parse the length byte for aid first, save the length `iLen` and increment `bOffset` to the next LV-pair. in the end the value and length of the applet data is taken and feeded into the `pin.update`.

In the given APDU, the PIN is acutally missing, try to parse the contents and length for aid and info and you will see that the applet data bytes are missing.